# A word for "modern" that doesn't imply "best"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I am thinking about textbooks in technical fields, whose titles are things like "modern computer technology".  These books may have been written many decades ago, so their contents very much do not reflect anything "modern" anymore.  Imagine such a book where there is a line like this:

"Modern hard drives can store megabytes of information and are so small that they can be lifted by a single person"

To us this sounds painfully archaic, but at the time the book was written that was really a marvel.

I was wondering if there is a word that could be used to future proof such writing, without using the word "modern" or "state of the art", which will become obsolete very fast in certain fields.

Comment: The information in the book would become dated just as quickly whether the title included the word 'modern' or not, so what's the point?

Comment: Sure there is. *Contemporary*.

Comment: I suppose it's just my own preference to avoid silly sounding lines like the ones above.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: fair enough.  Post it as an answer and I can accept it

Comment: @RegDwigнt Unqualified, *contemporary* suffers from exactly the same syndrome.

Comment: *Modern* doesn't convey anything to be embarrassed about.  If anything sounds embarrassingly dated, it's "so small."  The *so* shows a judgement about the size being impressive.  *Modern* carries no such judgement.

Comment: But *modern* ***doesn't*** always imply *best*. It's a matter of context. In many situations, you could say that *traditional* implies *best*. I also don't see how *modern* could fail to be relative to whatever year it happens to be. *Use modern technology* will apply just as much in 100 years as it does today. The problem with your example is not the use of *modern*, but the use of *megabytes*. Don't say *megabytes*. Say *a vast amount of information* instead. It will translate to whatever is available when read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Contemporary* marries the two meanings, "modern" and "specific to a certain time".

So when the reader sees it in a title of a textbook, they still understand it was modern *at the time*, but they will also invariably wonder *what time* that actually was and make sure to look at the publishing date.

Comment: See also my comment above.